# Download a file through FTP in TeamCity

Tags: ftp, teamcity

Is there an easy way (ideally a runner) to download a file through FTPS in TeamCity? I see that there are runners to upload files to FTP. I am looking to download a file from FTP server through TeamCity.

Answer (score 2):

There is no dedicated runner to download custom files, AFAIK.
But you can add ant-runner with simple ant script with `scp` task (for sftp) or `ftp` task (for ftp protocol) which will download file from ftp.
Ant is available on all agents. To add `scp` task you should specify `Additional Ant command line parameters` as `-lib "%teamcity.tool.ant-net-tasks%"` in ant runner parameters.

Comment: I used **WinSCP** and it worked like a charm. I used the powershell runner  based on the sample given [here](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles#example)

Comment: WinSCP would not work on linux agents ;) So I've recommended some crossplatform solution which is common to expect installed on agent: ant (as it bundles with TC). If you have only Windows/Linux agents you can use some powershell/bash scripts, yes, it's simpler.